# Entity Framework Code First: Initialize Identity Column with Seed and Increment Values

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have a fresh database and am looking to set the the seed and increment of the decimal identity column (example column below).

```
[Key, Column("id")]
public decimal id { get; set; }
```

Is it possible to set the seed AND the increment values? Would I have to modify the OnCreating() method?

Comment: Have you tried yourself before posting here?

Comment: Yes, I haven't seen a way to customize the increment value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may be able to add `Seed` for the `Identity` column in the following way

Consider the following `Student` class

```
public class Student
{
   [Key, Column("Id")]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now on it's Migration method add the `SQL` command [DBCC CHECKIDENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms176057.aspx) to set the Seed value of `100`

```
public override void Up()
{
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.Students",
        c => new
            {
                Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                Name = c.String(),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

    Sql("DBCC CHECKIDENT ('dbo.Students', RESEED, 100);");
}

public override void Down()
{
    DropTable("dbo.Students");
}
```

For changing the identity increment value, please see [this](http://improve.dk/working-with-identity-column-seed-and-increment-values/#Changing_the_identity_increment_value) to get idea.

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping I could avoid doing something like that, but it doesn't appear so.